# how to change mysql query to mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to change that mysql query to mongodb format. I can't find an answer on how to do it. Please suggest a solution.
I've tried several ways, but it doesn't work, please help
I know I have to use a aggregate query, but it's difficult because I have a lot of subqueries. How should I configure the stage?

```
SELECT @rowcnt := COUNT(*) AS cnt
    , SUM(keywordcount) AS total_k_count
    , SUM(exposecount) AS total_exp, SUM(clickcount) AS total_cc
    , IF( SUM(exposecount) = 0, 0, ROUND((SUM(clickcount) / SUM(exposecount))* 100, 2) ) AS total_cr
    , IF( SUM(clickcount) = 0, 0, ROUND(SUM(cost) / SUM(clickcount)) ) AS total_ccost
    , ROUND(SUM(cost)) AS total_cost
    , SUM(COUNT) AS total_count, SUM(directcount) AS total_d_count, SUM(indirectcount) AS total_ind_count
    , IF( SUM(clickcount) = 0, 0, ROUND( ( SUM(COUNT) / SUM(clickcount) ) * 100, 2) ) AS total_con_r
    , IF( SUM(COUNT) = 0, 0, ROUND((SUM(cost) / SUM(COUNT))) ) AS total_con_expense
    , SUM(conversioncost) AS total_con_cost, SUM(conversiondirectcost) AS total_con_d_cost, SUM(conversionindirectcost) AS total_con_ind_cost
    , IF( SUM(cost) = 0, 0, ROUND( ( SUM(conversioncost) / SUM(cost) * 100 ) ) ) AS total_roas
    FROM (
        SELECT a.s_date
         , a.master_id, REPLACE( c.media_name, '\'', '\`' ) AS media_name, a.media_code
         , b.keywordcount, SUM(a.exposecount) AS exposecount, SUM(a.clickcount) AS clickcount, SUM(a.cost) AS cost
         , IF( SUM(a.exposecount) = 0, 0, ROUND((SUM(a.clickcount) / SUM(a.exposecount))* 100, 2) ) AS clickrate
         , IF( SUM(a.clickcount)= 0, 0, ROUND( (SUM(a.cost) / SUM(a.clickcount)) , 2) ) AS clickcost
         , b.count, b.directcount, b.indirectcount
         , IF( SUM(a.clickcount) = 0, 0, ROUND((b.count / SUM(a.clickcount))* 100, 2) ) AS conversionrate
         , IF( b.count = 0, 0, ROUND((SUM(a.cost) / b.count)) ) AS conversionexpense
         , b.conversioncost, b.conversiondirectcost, b.conversionindirectcost
         , IF( SUM(a.cost) = 0, 0, ROUND(( b.conversioncost / SUM(a.cost)) * 100) ) AS roas
        FROM TMP_Report AS a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT nrc.media_code, COUNT(*) AS keywordcount, nrc.master_id, SUM(nrc.count) AS COUNT, SUM(nrc.directcount) AS directcount, SUM(nrc.indirectcount) AS indirectcount
            , SUM(nrc.conversioncost) AS conversioncost, SUM(nrc.conversiondirectcost) AS conversiondirectcost, SUM(nrc.conversionindirectcost) AS conversionindirectcost
            FROM (
                SELECT nrc.media_code, nrc.s_date, nrc.master_id, nrc.keyword_id, SUM(nrc.count) AS COUNT, SUM(nrc.directcount) AS directcount, SUM(nrc.indirectcount) AS indirectcount
                , SUM(nrc.cost) AS conversioncost, SUM(nrc.directcost) AS conversiondirectcost, SUM(nrc.indirectcost) AS conversionindirectcost
                FROM  TMP_ReportConv AS nrc
                GROUP BY nrc.master_id, nrc.keyword_id, media_code, s_date
            ) AS nrc
            INNER JOIN autoanswer.calendar AS c2 ON nrc.s_date = c2.cal_date
            GROUP BY nrc.master_id, nrc.media_code
        ) AS b ON a.master_id = b.master_id AND a.media_code = b.media_code
        LEFT OUTER JOIN naver.mst_media c ON a.media_code = c.media_id
        WHERE a.s_date BETWEEN $get_s_date AND $get_e_date
        GROUP BY a.master_id, a.media_code
    ) AS m;
```

Comment: You may have to write an Aggregation Query. Here is some related information: [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/).

Comment: Expressions like `IF( SUM(clickcount) = 0, 0, ROUND(SUM(cost) / SUM(clickcount)) )` might be better written as `ROUND(SUM(cost) / NULLIF(SUM(clickcount)),0)`

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result. What did you try so far?

Comment: Usually when you migrate each table to a collection one-by-one then you have a bad design. Typically the number of collections in NoSQL database like MongoDB is much less than the number of table in according relational SQL database like MySQL. Some NoSQL databases even do not support joins at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to do your job, but this could be a starting point:

```
db.TMP_Report.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {master_id: "$master_id", media_code: "$media_code"},
         count: { $count: {} },
         clickcount: { $sum: "$clickcount" },
         exposecount: { $sum: "$exposecount" }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         total_cr: { $round: [{ $multiply: [{ $divide: ["$clickcount", {$cond: ["$exposecount", "$exposecount", null]}] }, 100] }, 2] }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the good advice and comments